# Is jsp tag file compiled to Simple tags

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

In JSP, we have 3 ways to create tags:

1. Classic tag model
2. Simple tag model
3. Use JSP tag files (.tag extension)

I searched but I couldn't found the answer whether JSP tag files (.tag) compiled to Simple tags ( Or Classic tag). I think it will be generated to Simple tag because its body-content can not be JSP value but Not sure.

I read in http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnama.html, it says '**a tag file gets translated into a tag handler and then compiled**' It didn't say clearly the Tag handler is Classic or Simple tag handler.

Anyone has any ideas. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a definitive answer to the question, by if I look at the java class generated for a tag file by [jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/), it is a SimpleTag, as it extends [SimpleTagSupport](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/SimpleTagSupport.html).

```
public final class sample_tag
    extends javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.SimpleTagSupport
    implements org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspSourceDependent {

    (...)
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Why didn't I try it before.